# Passing string to csh and then to python script breaking spaces

Tags: python, csh, argv

I have a little CSH script that invokes a python script. I'm trying to pass a string to python script trought a CSH script but it is breaking the spaces, dificulting using argparse in python. I need this CSH script because after the python execution there are some legacy code that I need to use.

CSH script: 
Just the python script invocation, passing all the line arguments to python `sys.argv`

```
#!/bin/csh
echo  $argv[1-]
python soocc.py $argv[1-]
```

python script:
This script needs to identify a argument like: `-opt "+arg1=1 +arg2=3 +arg3=0"` before argparse parsing. So, first it identifies if there is a `-opt` in `sys.argv`, write the string in a variable and then remove `-opt "arg1=1 arg2=3 arg3=0"` from `sys.argv`. This way argparse will not process `-opt` (because argparse looks to +arg1 as a argument even if it is inside double quote).

```
#!usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# show sys.argv list
print sys.argv  
if '-opt' in sys.argv:
  xipdef.opt = sys.argv[sys.argv.index('-opt') + 1] #attributes the string after "-opt" to xipdef.opt
  sys.argv.remove(sys.argv[sys.argv.index('-opt') + 1])  # remove "<string>" from sys.argv
  sys.argv.remove(sys.argv[sys.argv.index('-opt')])  # remove "-opt" from sys.argv

print sys.argv
```

Problems:

```
soocc.csh -opt '"+arg1=1 +arg2=3 +arg3=0"'
```

Returns on csh echo:

```
-opt "+arg1=1 +arg2=3 +arg3=0"
```

So far so good. The problem is when the arguments are passed to python script. The first `print sys.argv` result is:

```
['soocc.csh','-opt', '"+arg1=1', '+arg2=3', '+arg3=0"']
```

The string inside double quotes is being break in space by `sys.argv`. I was expecting something like:

```
['soocc.csh','-opt', "+arg1=1 +arg2=3 +arg3=0"]
```

Someone could help me to find what is wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this *isn't* covered in "CSH Programming Considered Harmful", an excellent essay on why you should never use csh as a programming language, but it could probably be added.

Comment: This isn't an `argparse` issue.

Comment: You could use argparse technically to pass an arbitrary number of args with the "nargs=+" option.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy hacky...but this should work.

```
opts = []
holder = []
for arg in sys.argv:
    if '+' in arg:
        holder.append(arg.replace('"', ''))
    else:
        opts.append(arg)
holder = " ".join(holder)
opts.append(holder)
sys.argv = opts
print sys.argv
```

Tested